# missing ado net entity data model in visual studio 2015

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ado.net, entity

I am going to use asp.net 5 and entity framework 7.
for that i have created class library and want to add ado.net entity data model.
but in window i don't have an option of data for adding this ado.net entity data model.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvHir.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In the web project's project.json add:

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework": "4.1.10311",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta1"
}
```

In the **class libarary project** (data tier) add into the project.json the following dependencies:

**.NETCore 5.0**

```
EntityFramework.Relational.Design (>= 7.0.0-rc1-final)
Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final)
Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final)
```

**DNXCore 5.0**

```
EntityFramework.Relational.Design (>= 7.0.0-rc1-final)
Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final)
Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final)
System.Console (>= 4.0.0-beta-23516)
```

**.NETFramework 4.5.1**

```
EntityFramework.Relational.Design (>= 7.0.0-rc1-final)
```